# How to modify dependent: :destroy in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have two models, `Model1` and `Model2` as follows

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs :model1
end
```

I want to increase the destroy capability when I destroy a record in `Model1`. As well as the dependent records, I want to destroy `Model2` records that meet an attribute test as well. How can this be done?

Comment: Have an `after_destroy` callback for your attribute testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Active Record Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) to solve your problem. `after_destroy` may help you.

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model2s, dependent: :destroy

  after_destroy :increase_the_destroy_capability

  private

  def increase_the_destroy_capability
    # do some thing
  end
end
```